# CSS ::selection on Chrome

Tags: css, textselection

I am using css selection selector on my blog to override the default behaviour of browser text selection.

The code I use for `CSS` is given below.

```
::-moz-selection { background: #ea0000; color: #fff; text-shadow: none; }
::selection { background: #ea0000; color: #fff; text-shadow: none; }
```

It works on Firefox and IE, but when using Chrome the selection overflows to other areas. Any ideas?

Here's how to test my problem from my blog: semihyagcioglu.com

Comment: Maybe you could try `::-webkit-selection`.

Comment: @Tom: There is no `::-webkit-selection`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hide the overflow on your `article` elements:

```css
article {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[image: Example]